# Excel vba Sorting Criteria –different orientations

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro for sorting entries in four different sheets. Two of these I want to sort oriented left to right, while the other two must be sorted top to bottom. Right now the code looks roughly as follows (don’t mind "MyRange” and “OtherRange” – they are variables decided outside this code):

```
        If MySheet.Name = "Shippers" _
        Or MySheet.Name = "Consignees" _
        Then
            MySheet.sort.SortFields.Clear
            MySheet.sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("MyRange”), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With MySheet.sort
            .SetRange Range(“OtherRange”)
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight '<---
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        Else
            MySheet.sort.SortFields.Clear
            MySheet.sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("MyRange”), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With MySheet.sort
            .SetRange Range(“OtherRange”)
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom '<---
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        End If
```

The only real difference between the two blocks is the “.Orientation” – row. My question is: Is there any way to merge these two blocks and set “.Orientation” to either xlTopToBottom or xlLeftToRight  depending on the sheet name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xl~ constants are `Long` values, you can just assign them to a variable before the block.

```
Dim OrntValue As Long
Select Case MySheet.Name
    Case "Shippers", "Consignees"
        OrntValue = xlLeftToRight
    Case Else
        OrntValue = xlTopToBottom
End Select
...
.Orientation = OrntValue
```

`IIf` might be another option, but I'd prefer this one.